# How to create a scoreboard in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I have a game where I want to display a scoreboard with the previous highscores. I also want to see these scores even if I re-open the app. Is it possible to display it in a TextView? Also, how am I supposed to save the scores locally?

Comment: use `SharedPreference` for storing data

Comment: Please extend your question with what you tried thus far (code samples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how am I supposed to save the scores locally?

You would use a database. There are a number of libraries to simplify it, I recommend [SugarORM](https://github.com/satyan/sugar).

> Is it possible to display it in a TextView

No. You'll almost always want something more than a single `TextView`. That said, what to use depends a lot on the layout you want to have.